# Error whenever I try to geocode

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, shapely, pycharm

I used this code to calculate my centroid and the centriod co-ordinates I get is "314167.7583680855,239312.8503371872". however whenever I try to geocode this co-ordinate I get an error.

ERROR:

> DeprecationWarning: Unable to parse the string as Point: "Latitude must be in the [-90; 90] range.". Using the value as-is for the query. In geopy 2.0 this will become an exception.

```
with fiona.open(DESTINATION_FILE) as input:
input.schema['geometry'] = "Point"
with fiona.open(.cache/centroid.shp, 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', input.schema.copy(), input.crs) as output:
    for elem in input:
        if elem['id'] == '0':
            geom = shape(elem['geometry'])
            elem['geometry'] = mapping(geom.centroid)
            print(geom.centroid)
            output.write(elem)
 import pyproj
 import geopy_nominatim
 from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

 geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my-application")
 location = geolocator.reverse("314167.7583680855,239312.8503371872")
 print(location)
```

Any ideas on how I can correct this flaw?

Comment: 314167.7583680855,239312.8503371872 needs to be reprojected to latitude & longitude to reverse geocode with nomination like https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=geojson&lat=40.712776&lon=-74.005974  see https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Reverse/

Comment: That is my problem I don't know how to change it to lat and long

Comment: your shapefile (centroid.shp) should have a .prj file (open in a text editor) it will tell you the projection.